# How to animate images when swiping a View

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have two UIViewController,I use the SwipeGesture to navigate between the two views.
The first view contains some UIImageView.How can I make images animated when I swipe down the first View.How I can make images  follow finger position? I would like to do something like DropBox Carousel first view?